# Use Angular-Datatable in Umbraco 7 custom section

Tags: angularjs, umbraco, datatables

I am trying to use an angular datatable with server side processing in my umbraco custom section. My problem is that when I use this line:

```
angular.module('umbraco', ['datatables'])
```

if I include the datatables dependency I get the following error:

```
angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:63 Error: Argument 'Umbraco.MainController' is not a function, got undefined
    at Error (native)
    at cb (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:17:114)
    at xa (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:17:187)
    at $get (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:53:310)
    at http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:44:274
    at n (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:7:74)
    at k (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:44:139)
    at e (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:40:139)
    at e (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:40:156)
    at e (http://localhost:65055/umbraco/lib/angular/1.1.5/angular.min.js?cdv=886402897:40:156)
```

this is my package.manifest:

```
javascript : [      
            '~/App_Plugins/BlogShop/backoffice/BlogShopTree/js/jquery.dataTables.js',
            '~/App_Plugins/BlogShop/backoffice/BlogShopTree/js/angular-datatables.js',
            '~/App_Plugins/BlogShop/backoffice/BlogShopTree/js/serverSideProcessing.js',    
    ],
```

This is the controller:

```
angular.module('umbraco',['datatables']).controller('datatable.Controller', function (DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('ajax', {
            // Either you specify the AjaxDataProp here
            // dataSrc: 'data',
            url: '/angular-datatables/data/serverSideProcessing',
            type: 'POST'
        })
     // or here
     .withDataProp('data')
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Name').withTitle('First name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Father').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
    ];
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="datatable.Controller as showCase">
            <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this ...https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/54389-AngularJS-dependencies-for-backend-

Comment: with: var app = angular.module('umbraco', []);
app.requires.push('datatables'); i keep getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the 'umbraco' module is being recreated rather than retrieved. The following is quoted from the [official anguljs module docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)

> **Creation versus Retrieval**
>
> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

^This effectively destroys the dependencies set elsewhere (like those from umbraco).  Your usage of datatables seems that you don't need 
Try with the following.  I'm afraid i can't test this code withyour example 100% as i don't have your serverside backing, but the approach is tested and is a pattern that i have used extensively. The big difference is not including the [requires argument](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) which, if specified - (re)creates the module.

```
var app = angular.module("umbraco");
        app.requires.push('datatables'); 

        app.controller('datatable.Controller', function (DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
            vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('ajax', {
                    // Either you specify the AjaxDataProp here
                    // dataSrc: 'data',
                    url: '/angular-datatables/data/serverSideProcessing',
                    type: 'POST'
                })
             // or here
             .withDataProp('data')
                .withOption('processing', true)
                .withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
            vm.dtColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Id').withTitle('ID'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Name').withTitle('First name'),
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Father').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
            ];
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem

Comment: @Pau did you make angular datatables work with umbraco 7? How? As far as I know it requires angular in version >= 1.3 but umbraco uses 1.1.5...

Comment: Doing the same as mentioned above I got the following error: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.toString (native) at Function.x.extend.type " for the basic angular datatables example.